# Redirect from Blazor Component(.razor) to Razor Page(.cshtml) [ServerSide]

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

Here's my use case. I have a singleton object that is holding global site state. I have a button on my website that when clicked fires an event on the global site state object. I have a Blazor component(razor) that is listening for this event. It responds to the event by doing this

```cs
var path = "siteupdate".AddInitialQueryStringArg("returnUrl", _navManager.Uri);
_navManager.NavigateTo(path,true);
```

The idea is that all online users are redirected to a Razor page(.cshtml) that has a message saying "The Website is being updated, come back later". This is a requirement to provide a decent user experience for when the server goes down temporarily for an update and loses connection to the SignalR hub.

Following the execution it appears as if the navigator tries to navigate to the `siteupdate` page but it ends up getting rejected and resets back to whatever component I was on when I make the call. Similar to when you try to update the url in the browser manually and the navmanager resets it. Putting breakpoints in my Razor Page I can tell that the `OnGet` method gets called most of the time, but it seems like it's response is not being acknowledge or something? I've tried the following :

Attempted to set window location via javascript

```cs
var path = "/update".AddInitialQueryStringArg("returnUrl", _navManager.Uri);
JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorHelpers.RedirectTo", path);
```

Attempted to not use force reload, this results in a 404

```cs
var path = "/siteupdate".AddInitialQueryStringArg("returnUrl", _navManager.Uri);
_navManager.NavigateTo(path);
```

For reference I have the Razor page under
Pages/SiteUpdate/UpdateLandingPage.cshtml
I tried placing it just under the Pages folder, but like I said earlier the `OnGet` method is getting called so the router seems to be finding it, but it seems like the framework is overwriting the URL somehow.

Thanks

Comment: Can you access the siteupdate page from a fresh browser window? If not, check your Routing/Endpoint configuration

Comment: Good question, and yes if I open a new tab and enter the address manually it works just fine.

Comment: Have you monitored the browser requests in the browser dev tools network tab - to see what requests/responses are happening?

Comment: I get a weird "blocked"  or something that Immediately disappears as the previous page is reloaded. I think @Quarango is onto something with the navigation between blazor components(.razor) and razor pages (.cshtml) is a little more complicated in this case.

Comment: You can tick a box in browser dev tools to retain history (called "preserve log" in Edge) so you don't lose captured requests - you need to see what is happening - it sounds like the siteupdate page is redirecting immediately, but you can confirm that by capturing the response

Answer (score 1):

You have two parts to your problem: a common update service that all users see, and the individual page a user is on when the update occurs which sets the redirect. These would need `Singleton` and `Scoped` contexts respectively.

I tested this out creating two services:

###### UpdateService.cs

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// A singleton service that alerts users about updates
    /// </summary>
    public class UpdateService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Event raised when an update starts
        /// </summary>
        public event Action OnUpdate;

        public void TriggerUpdate()
        {
            // trigger the event
            OnUpdate?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

This has an event `OnUpdate` that consumers can subscribe to when the update occurs.

###### RedirectService.cs

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Redirect service (user-scoped)
    /// </summary>
    public class RedirectService : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly NavigationManager navigationManager;
        private readonly UpdateService updateService;

        public RedirectService(NavigationManager navigationManager, 
                               UpdateService updateService)
        {
            this.navigationManager = navigationManager;
            this.updateService = updateService;
            // register for updates
            this.updateService.OnUpdate += HandleUpdate;
        }

        private void HandleUpdate()
        {
            // get user's current URL
            var uri = new Uri(navigationManager.Uri);

            if (!uri.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/siteupdate", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                // redirect
                navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/siteupdate?redirectUrl={uri.PathAndQuery}");
            }
        }

        // Cleanup
        public void Dispose()
        {
            updateService.OnUpdate -= HandleUpdate;
        }
    }
```

This service consumes the `UpdateService` and listens for `OnUpdate` events. If the current URL isn't already "/siteupdate" it redirects the user.

In `Startup.cs` you register these two services

```
// a singleton service - all users share this
services.AddSingleton<UpdateService>();
// scoped service for the redirect
services.AddScoped<RedirectService>();
```

The order is important since `RedirectService` needs the `UpdateService`.

To get this to trigger I just injected the service in `MainLayout.razor`:

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject Data.RedirectService redirectService
```

To test this I put a button on `Index.razor` and when clicked that user and all other users on different pages/browsers all redirected to the new page.

That means that any user on any page *except* `/siteupdate` will be redirected. If that's not your use-case (e.g. only some pages/users should redirect) you can adapt accordingly.

Comment: Is the siteupdate endpoint in your project a razor page or a blazor component? Still getting the same results as I was before where if I try to navigate without the force reload parameter, the nav manager seems to be expecting the endpoint to be a blazor component so returns page not found. With force reload, it hits the correct page but is reset somehow back to the original page.

Comment: SiteUpdate was a Blazor page: `SiteUpdate.razor` with a `@page "/siteupdate"` route at the start. This technique will only work for Blazor pages - if you want to also redirect _Razor Pages_ (which are `.cshtml`) you'll need a JS-based system using some kind of push tech such as SignalR. That's way more complicated

Comment: @GeorgeFabish can I clarify: are you trying to use `NavigationManager` in Razor pages (.cshtml)? `NavigationManager` is a Blazor routing service: not designed to work in cshtml

Comment: As the title says I would like to navigate from a blazor component to a Razor page .cshtml.  Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. The reason I can't just navigate to another blazor component is when the site goes offline for an update the user loses their SignalR connection so the landing page does them no good in that instance.

Comment: You can navigate to a Razor page from Blazor.. but not if the site's updating - my code won't work in that scenario since it's part of Blazor.

Comment: Can you give me any guidance on where to look to see how to implement a JS Interop to handle this?

Comment: No - because JSinterop would be part of Blazor, which isn't working.. so it won't work. You need a totally different solution